# How to get a list of All pages belonging to a Wikipedia Portal?

Tags: wikipedia

I was wondering, is there a way to get the entire list of articles (pages) filed under a Wikipedia Portal?

For example, I want to get a list of All the pages filed under [Linguistics Portal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal%3aLinguistics), is there a way to do it?

As another example, [Java Portal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal%3aJava) states that it has "1482 pages so far!", however where are these 1482 pages? Is there a list that shows these pages?

Comment: Portals don't have a list of pages associated with them. As an alternative, you could look for articles the are in a certain category (and its subcategories), or articles that belong under a certain WikiProject.

Comment: @svick How do we search for the 1482 pages that Java Portal claims it has? : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal%3aJava

Comment: I'm not sure what does that number mean, but it's certainly not up-to-date, since [it was last updated in 2010](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Portal:Java/Number_of_articles&action=history). It most likely means [the number of articles in WikiProject Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:WikiProject_Java/Assessment#Assessment_statistics).

Comment: @svick How do we get access to all of these articles? (instead of linking from 1 article to the next to the next to the next..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no articles associated with a portal directly.

If you want to get all articles in a WikiProject ([WikiProject Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aWikiProject_Java) in this case), you need to get all articles in subcategories of the corresponding assessment category.
In this case, it's [Category:Java articles by quality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aJava_articles_by_quality).

Be aware that assessment categories don't contain the articles, but their talk pages.

Comment: Thanks for the reply =D Btw Wikipedia's main page http://goo.gl/LPrA states that there are 4m articles in English. So what's the easiest way to navigate through these pages? Isn't there some sort of table of contents or something?

Comment: That entirely depends on what kind of navigation do you have in mind. But using Wikipedia categories might be a good idea. The root is [Category:Contents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Contents) for all pages and [Category:Articles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Articles) for articles specifically.

Comment: Cool, that works for a top-to-bottom approach, however from a page, is there anyway to navigate *upwards*? For example, in the category "Grammatical Gender" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Grammatical_gender we can see that there is a page (also) called "Grammatical Gender" filed under that category. However, from the page "Grammatical Gender" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_gender, how do we navigate *upwards* and see which category it is filed under?

Comment: Look at the bottom of the article. All categories that article belongs to are listed there.